# submit form is automatically triggered

Tags: 7, forms

I have a from that allows user to select a list of sites and get a list of users from those sites. It presents the list both as a HTML table and as a csv file that is saved to the local machine

the form is working but it is auto submitting when I click on it, so it just prompt me with a save csv file every time even though I did not physically click on submit.

What am I missing?

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */

function myModule_menu() {
  $items['admin/reports/myModule'] = array(
    'title' => 'List of publishers and contributors',
    'description' => 'List of pub and contrib',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('myModule_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Page callback: my module settings
 *
 */
function myModule_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $header = array('domain' => t('Sites to gather users from (click to select all)'));
  $options = myModule_get_domains();

  $index = 1;
  $sites_selection = variable_get('myModule_sites_selection','');

  foreach ($options as $key => $domain) {

    if ($sites_selection[$index] == $domain['domain']) {
      $default_values[$index] = TRUE;
    }
    $index = $index+1;
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );

  $form['myModule_sites_selection'] = array(
   '#type' => 'tableselect',
   '#header' => $header,
   '#options' => $options,
   '#default_value' => $default_values,
   '#attributes' => array('id' => 'tableselect-id', 'class' => array('tableselect-class')),
   '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
  );

  $form['submit2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );

  $form['some_text'] = array(
    '#markup' => myModule_admin_get()
  );

  return $form;
}

function myModule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $options = myModule_get_domains();

  $sites_array = array();
  $index = 1;
  foreach($form_state['values']['myModule_sites_selection'] as $value) {
    if ($form_state['values']['myModule_sites_selection'][$index] == $index) {
      $sites_array[$index] = $options[$index]['domain'];
    }
    $index++;
  }

  // store domain names in variable, index don't work for default_value setting (0)
  variable_set('myModule_sites_selection', $sites_array);
  drupal_set_message(t('Review users below.'));
}

/**
 * Implements hook_permisson().
 */
function myModule_permission() {
  return array('configure utilities administration' => array(
    'title' => t('Configure utilities admin'),
    'description' => t('Allow user to configure utilities admin.'),
  ));
}

function myModule_admin_get() {
  $check_domains = variable_get('myModule_sites_selection');
  $output = '<table border="1">';
  $output .= '<th>Domain</th><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>NetID</th><th>Role</th><th>Status</th><th>Last access</th>';

  foreach($check_domains as $index => $domain) {
    // call domain to get its users
    $output .= myModule_process_site_users($domain);
  }

  $output .= '</table>';

  return $output;
}

function myModule_process_site_users($domain) {
  $data = 'user=life&password=science';
  $options = array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'data' => $data,
            'timeout' => 15,
            'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
            );
  $users = drupal_http_request('http://'.$domain.'/api/v1/userslist', $options);

  global $user;
  $role = $user->roles;
  $is_admin = in_array("administrator", $role);
  if (!$is_admin){
     return '<tr><td colspan="6" align="center"><strong>You are not an Administrator</td></tr>';
  }

  $users_array = json_decode($users->data);
  $list = array();
  foreach ($users_array as $key => $value) {
      $output .= '<tr>';
      $output .= '<td>' . $domain .'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>' . $value->name .'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'. $value->email .'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'. $value->netID .'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'. $value->role .'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'. $value->status .'</td>';
      $output .= '<td>'. $value->last_access .'</td>';
      $output .= '</tr>';
      $list[] = array($domain, $value->name, $value->email, $value->netID, $value->role, $value->status, $value->last_access);
  }

  myModule_export_to_csv($list);
  return $output;
}

/**
* Get all sites from a JSON file. If this is a local environment, use hardcoded sites.
*/
function get_all_sites() {

  $sites = '';
  if (isset($_ENV['AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT'])) {
    $all_sites = json_decode(file_get_contents('/var/www/html/site.'.$_ENV['AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT'].'/docroot/sites/all/drush/sites.json'));
    switch ($_ENV['AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT']) {
      case 'dev':
        $sites = $all_sites->dev;
        break;

      case 'test':
        $sites = $all_sites->test;
        break;

      case 'prod':
        $sites = $all_sites->prod;
        break;
    }
  } else {
    $sites = json_decode('{"me": "site.me","you": "site.you","thee": "site.thee"}');
  }

  return $sites;

}

/**
* Get all domain after a JSON file was found.
*/
function myModule_get_domains($sites) {

  $sites = get_all_sites();

  $domains = array ();
  $index = 1;
  foreach($sites as $site => $domain) {
    // $domains[$domain] = $domain; // $options can't have string offset
    //  start options array at 1 rather than zero to get around bug with 0 index being always false
    $domains[$index] = array('domain' => $domain);
    // $domains[$index] = $domain;
    $index++;
  }

  return $domains;

}

function myModule_export_to_csv($list){
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=csvfile.csv');

  $header = array('Domain','Name','Email','NetID','Role','Status','Last access');
  fputcsv($fp, $header);
  $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
  foreach($list as $line){
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
  }
  fclose($fp);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the HTML/JS. You might have a wrong HTML tag wrapping everything and that may be triggering it on click. Or you have something wrong with JS.

Comment: Everything looks fine with respect to js/html